# AngularJS jasmine promise testing fails because of timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, q

I'm trying to test my login controller, which looks like this:

```
describe('LoginController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('task6'));

    var $controller, LoginService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _LoginService_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;
    }));

    describe('LoginController.submitLogin', function() {
        it('tests if such user exists', function(done) {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', {$scope: $scope});
            var resultValue;
            controller.loginField = 'John';
            controller.password = 'Smith';

            LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField,
                                controller.password)
            .then(function() {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
                done();
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Where signIn function is:

```
function signIn(loginField, password) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
   if (loginField && password) {
        defer.resolve("nice one");
   } else {
        defer.reject("oh dear");
   }
   return defer.promise;
}
```

But it always fails with "Async callback was not invoken within timeout specified..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$digest()` once at the end of your test. A promise will never be resolved within the same digest cycle it has been created in.

**Explanation**

While it would be possible for the framework to allow this, the developers chose not to. See this example while it could be problematic:

```
function login(login, password) {
    LoginService.signIn(login, password)
        .then(function() {
            cancelLoadingAnimation();
        });

    startLoadingAnimation(); 
}
```

Usually a promise is resolved asynchronously, so we don't have a problem here. The loading animation is started in the login function and cancelled when signing in succeeded. But imagine the promise was instantly resolved (for instance in a test like yours)! It would now be possible that the animation was cancelled before it was even started.

Of course this can be cured by moving the call of `startLoadingAnimation()` above the call to `signIn()`. However, it is much easier to reason about your code when promises are always resolved asynchronously.

**Update:** As @gnerkus states in his answer, you have to create the `$scope` as a child of the `$rootScope`. However, this alone will not solve the problem. You will have to do both.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `scope` object for the controller as an instance of `$rootScope`:

```
describe('LoginController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('task6'));

  var $controller, LoginService;

  // Inject the $rootScope service for use in creating new scope objects.
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$controller_, _LoginService_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    LoginService = _LoginService_;
  }));

  describe('LoginController.submitLogin', function() {
    it('tests if such user exists', function(done) {
      // Create a new scope for the controller.
      var scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var controller = $controller('LoginController', {$scope: scope});
      var resultValue;
      controller.loginField = 'John';
      controller.password = 'Smith';

      LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField,
                            controller.password)
        .then(function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
            done();
        }); 
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, @gnerkus and @lex82 were both right - I need to run $digest cycle for promises, but I still need a reference to a real scope to do this. Here is the final, working version of my code:

```
describe('LoginController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('task6'));

    var $rootScope, $controller, LoginService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _LoginService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;
    }));

    describe('LoginController.submitLogin', function() {
        it('tests if such user exists', function(done) {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var controller = $controller('LoginController', 
                                         {$scope: $scope});
            controller.loginField = 'John';
            controller.password = 'Smith';
            LoginService.signIn(controller.loginField,
                                controller.password)
            .then(function(logged) {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
                done();
            })
            $scope.$digest();
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you, guys!